# How to open a GRIB file

Tags: r, grid, arcgis

I have this GRIB file containing meteorological data: [alaro.grb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8csMw0e6YalZldzSnNVYkptd1E)

I'm trying to open this file using different software but without luck so far. Here is what I tried:

Using R:

```
library(rgdal)
gribfile <- "alaro.grb"
grib <- readGDAL(gribfile)
```

> alaro.grb is a grib file, but no raster dataset was successfully identified.

```
library(rNOMADS)
GribInfo(gribfile)

> "grib1 message ignored (use wgrib)"
```

So I figured it is a GRIB-1 file.

```
GribInfo(gribfile, file.type = "grib1")
```

> Error in system(paste0("wgrib ", grib.file), " -s", intern = TRUE) : 
>      'ignore.stdout' must be TRUE or FALSE

The I used `wgrib` directly in a `cmd` window to gather information:

```
wgrib alaro.grb -V
```

which leads to

> rec 1:0:date 2014061306 TMP kpds5=11 kpds6=105 kpds7=2 levels=(0,2) grid=255 2 m above gnd 2hr fcst:
>     TMP=Temp. [K]
>     timerange 0 P1 2 P2 0 TimeU 1  nx 508 ny 446 GDS grid 0 num_in_ave 1 missing 0
>     center 224 subcenter 0 process 1 Table 1 scan: WE:SN winds(grid) 
>     latlon: lat  37.310000 to 55.110000 by 0.040000  nxny 226568
>             long 2.000000 to 32.420000 by 0.060000, (508 x 446) scan 64 mode 136 bdsgrid 1
>     min/max data 276.842 304.709  num bits 12  BDS_Ref 276.842  DecScale 0 BinScale -7
>
> rec 2:340424:date 2014061306 APCP kpds5=61 kpds6=1 kpds7=0 levels=(0,0) grid=255 sfc 1-2hr acc:
>     APCP=Total precipitation [kg/m^2]
>     timerange 4 P1 1 P2 2 TimeU 1  nx 508 ny 446 GDS grid 0 num_in_ave 1 missing 0
>     center 224 subcenter 0 process 1 Table 1 scan: WE:SN winds(grid) 
>     latlon: lat  37.310000 to 55.110000 by 0.040000  nxny 226568
>             long 2.000000 to 32.420000 by 0.060000, (508 x 446) scan 64 mode 136 bdsgrid 1
>     min/max data 0 7.13696  num bits 16  BDS_Ref 0  DecScale 0 BinScale -13
>
> rec 3:794132:date 2014061306 SNMR kpds5=171 kpds6=1 kpds7=0 levels=(0,0) grid=255 sfc 2hr fcst:
>     SNMR=Snow mixing ratio [kg/kg]
>     timerange 0 P1 2 P2 0 TimeU 1  nx 508 ny 446 GDS grid 0 num_in_ave 1 missing 0
>     center 224 subcenter 0 process 1 Table 1 scan: WE:SN winds(grid) 
>     latlon: lat  37.310000 to 55.110000 by 0.040000  nxny 226568
>             long 2.000000 to 32.420000 by 0.060000, (508 x 446) scan 64 mode 136 bdsgrid 1
>     min/max data 0 1  num bits 8  BDS_Ref 0  DecScale 0 BinScale -7
>
> rec 4:1021272:date 2014061306 CNWAT kpds5=223 kpds6=1 kpds7=0 levels=(0,0) grid=255 sfc 1-2hr acc:
>     CNWAT=Plant canopy surface water [kg/m^2]
>     timerange 4 P1 1 P2 2 TimeU 1  nx 508 ny 446 GDS grid 0 num_in_ave 1 missing 0
>     center 224 subcenter 0 process 1 Table 1 scan: WE:SN winds(grid) 
>     latlon: lat  37.310000 to 55.110000 by 0.040000  nxny 226568
>             long 2.000000 to 32.420000 by 0.060000, (508 x 446) scan 64 mode 136 bdsgrid 1
>     min/max data 27039.5 2.87254e+06  num bits 16  BDS_Ref 27039.5  DecScale 0 BinScale 6

With this information I returned to R and tried:

```
ReadGrib(gribfile, variables = "CNWAT", levels = c(0,0), file.type = "grib1")
> $meta.data
NULL

$value
NULL

$variables
NULL

$levels
NULL

$grib.type
[1] "grib1"
```

So it seems there is no data `wgrib` can read.

I also tried to open the file using `ArcGIS` with the error:

> Could not open the specified file.

Comment: wgrib gives me a `Undefined parameter table (center 224-0 table 1), using NCEP-opn`, and gribscan crashes after the first record. So I wonder if the file is corrupted or invalid somehow? Has anyone managed to read it? Other grib (version 1) files I've downloaded work fine.

Comment: I managed to read it using `wgrib`. It indeed gives the message but is still able to read it. Somehow `ReadGrib` fails though which is weird since it uses `wgrib` as well.